# The ways to make a scraper bot look more like a human

Tags: proxy, web-scraping, vpn

Due to a limitation of the API of a websites I use for searching some products, I have to do html scraping its Products page. There's no no other way because it offers only free API with the limitation. I just need 10 or 100 times more items that its API returns, meaning even if I call it 5 times, it'll return the same set of the products as if it were 1 call.

I don't need to scrape plenty of the page in short period of time. Normally a scrape bot would scrape all that data in a few minutes. For me a few hours is acceptable, so my scraper can be more like a human.

The questions is: what are the ways to make my scraper look like a normal user?

> 1. First, make less calls in a short period of time.
> 2. Use a headless browser, maybe?
> 3. Use vpn? or proxy? or both?

What are other pointers?

Note: in my case scraping is the only way to achieve what I want because the API doesn't work. So there's no question whether I should use the API or scraping. I simply can only use scraping.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically heading toward a right direction.

Yet I suspect that you don't really master the API (or it's a weird one) if `if call it 5 times, it'll return the same set of the products as if it were 1 call.` API should be able to let users access to all possible data (with frequency limit though).

The items you've asked about:

1. Make less calls in a short period of time. - Kind of true, yet still you should be clear what request frequency is acceptible for certain site (not being detected, nor bandwidth throttling).
2. Use a headless browser. - Yes. Abandon cookie, be anonymous.
3. Use vpn? or proxy? - Proxy yes, use an appropriate proxy service that will provide you enough flexibility of not being detected. VPN does not help, since network nodes (where you scrape from) are limited in number and have static IPs (basically).

I think [this post](https://webscraping.pro/7-ways-to-protect-website-from-scraping-and-how-to-bypass-this-protection/) might be to your help.